# Move-SPUser : pixels

Tags: 2010, active-directory, user-profile-service, powershell

Migrating users from one domain to another, I get this error on a couple of users. The migration still seems to occur.

```
Move-SPUser : pixels
At D:\UserMigration\MigrateUsers.ps1:10 char:28
+   $siteUser | Move-SPUser <<<<  -NewAlias $user.usernameAfter -IgnoreSID
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...PCmdletMoveUser:
   SPCmdletMoveUser) [Move-SPUser], UserProfileException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletMoveUser
```

I loaded up a CSV full of before/after usernames and ran it on the list, and two of the users generated this error.

$user is just the CSV row, usernameAfter is the second column in that row.

$siteUser is an SPUser object created from $site.RootWeb.AllUsers[$user.usernameBefore].

Paraphrased script used:

```
$users = Import-CSV D:\UserMigration\MigrateTheseUsers.txt
$site = Get-SPSite https://sharepointsite.com
$web = $site.RootWeb

foreach($user in $users)
{
  $siteUser = $web.AllUsers[$user.usernameBefore]
  Write-Host User Before:
  $siteUser
  $siteUser | Move-SPUser -NewAlias $user.usernameAfter -IgnoreSID
  $siteUser = $web.AllUsers[$user.usernameAfter]
  Write-Host User After:
  $siteUser
}
```

Is this something I should be concerned about?

**Update 1**
Okay, I have one additional user that I receive this error for and the user *does not* get migrated. As circumstance has it, that user is my boss. Both a source and target user profile exist already but this has not been a problem in the past.

**Update 2**
I tried using stsadm instead to do the migration. I got the same result, without the PowerShell exception wrapper. I think this may be a generic exception bubbling up from the object model that just, for whatever reason, contains the text "pixels".

ULS shows the following error in the logs:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
  Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.UserInfo' with unique index 'UserInfo_Login'.
  The statement has been terminated.
```

Without digging too deep into SQL, I'm not really sure what I can do about this without tainting the explicit "No direct DB operations!" rule of SharePoint. The relevant index is on the site ID, the login, and the deleted flag. I know I've migrated users before that have used both their old and new accounts at the same time, so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: O_o I fear the answer, but... "pixels" is by any way the alias of one of your user? I can't think of a reason for a similar message.

Comment: Negative. This error occurred for three different users, and as far as I'm aware, none of them would even know what pixels are without some prodding beforehand.

Comment: Are you sure your import csv is correct? There is no loginname twice?
Why you are not using the command as one liner? foreach($user in $users)
{Move-SPUser –Identity $user.usernameBefore –NewAlias $user.usernameAfter  -IgnoreSID}

Comment: The CSV is fine. I get the error doing the same command inline. Read Update 2 - it's bubbling up from STSADM so it isn't a command execution issue.

Comment: I know this post is old but I just did a stsadm -o migrateuser and the only thing it returned was the word 'pixels' as well.. I see the user appear twice in the permissions. no idea whats going on